# Number of ways in which a composite number can be resolved into 2 coprimes?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations

for example 210 = 2*3*5*7,number of relative primes is 2**(4-1) =8,please help me derive this result.here's my try = 4C0+4C1+4C2+4C3+4C4=2**4 .Since nCr = nCn-r we decide this by two.4C0 couples with 4C4 ,4C1 couples with 4C3 but 4C2 is left.The idea I apply is that when we select r objects out of n,n-r are automatically selected.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80578/how-many-ways-a-composite-number-can-be-resolved-into-two-factors-which-are-prim

Comment: This is a duplicate of the other question, but your attempt is also correct. (Because $\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \dots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n$ for any $n$.) The key is to look at the number of distinct primes in the factorisation.

Comment: can you explain in the way I am proceeding,when n is odd,the number of terms in binomial expansion are even and all form pairs,but the problem is when n is even ,and the number of terms in binomial expansion is odd

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the number of terms is odd or even -- it is always true that (in your notation) nC0 + nC1 + ... + nCn is $2^n$. That's the answer. (You don't even need to use the fact that nCr = nCn-r etc.)

Comment: but the answer is 2*(n-1)?thats when the problem with terms being odd kicks in

Comment: The answer is $2^{n-1}$ not $2(n-1)$. Observe these:
$$\binom30+\binom31+\binom32+\binom33=2^3$$
$$\binom40+\binom41+\binom42+\binom43+\binom44=2^4$$
$$\binom50+\binom51+\binom52+\binom53+\binom54+\binom55=2^5$$
Whether $m$ is odd or even, it is always true that $\binom{m}0+\binom{m}1+\dots+\binom{m}m=2^m$. For your problem, just note that each way of dividing $n$ into an unordered pair $\{a,b\}$ gets counted twice (when you count ordered pairs) as $(a,b)$ and as $(b,a)$, so you should divide $2^n$ by two, which gives $2^n/2=2^{n-1}$. For more, see the other question (whose duplicate this is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$. If you want to split this number in two coprimes, you need to know how many different ways there are to put this $n$ different primes in two stacks. So the question is the same as: "How many ways are there to split a set in two?".

Comment: I know that but please help me with my problem with the question,ie  odd vs even

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The answer is $1 + 4 + 6 = 11$
Not sure where you get the answer $8$.

My mistake: The final 6 double counts the pairs so you are right, it is
$$1 + 4 + 6/2 = 8$$ is the answer.

Comment: How do you get $11$? The answer is $8$.

Comment: You are right. See my edit